# Memory leaks problem with using TsoapAttachment in SOAP WebService (Delphi)

Tags: delphi

I create a simple webservie, and I have a problem with application memory growth.

WebService:

```
// Impl File
type

  { T_Service }
  T_Service = class(TInvokableClass, I_Service)
  public
    function Convert(ReqAttach: TSOAPAttachment): TSOAPAttachment; stdcall;
  end;
  
implementation

function T_Service.Convert(
  ReqAttach: TSOAPAttachment): TSOAPAttachment;
var
  memStream : TMemoryStream;
  outStream : TMemoryStream;  
 try
    ReqAttach.SaveToStream(memStream);
    outStream.LoadFromFile('D:\Out.pdf');
    RetAttach.SetSourceStream(outStream, soReference);
  finally
    memStream.Free;
  end;
end;

initialization
{ Invokable classes must be registered }
   InvRegistry.RegisterInvokableClass(T_Service);
end.
```

```
//Intf file
type

  I_Service = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{69440128-AC9D-43CC-9A11-7B6B36F15D1E}']
  function Convert(ReqAttach: TSOAPAttachment): TSOAPAttachment; stdcall;
end;
implementation

initialization
  { Invokable interfaces must be registered }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(I_Service));

end.
```

My Client

```
procedure TClientForm.btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ReqAttach: TSOAPAttachment;
  RespAttach: TSOAPAttachment;
  Service: I_Service;
begin
  ReqAttach := TSOAPAttachment.Create;
  Service := unitIMyService.GetI_Service();
  try
    try
      ReqAttach.SetSourceFile('D:\In.pdf');
      RespAttach := Service.Convert(ReqAttach);
      RespAttach.SaveToFile('D:\Resp.pdf');
    finally
      FreeAndNil(ReqAttach);
      FreeAndNil(RespAttach);
    end;
  except
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Every time I execute btnClick action webservice growth 0.2MB (Out.pdf size). Ofcourse it return back desired file.

- GetI_Service is in autogenerated file from WSDL
- Ultimately, the website is to convert the uploaded file in TSoapAttachment and return it as TSoapAttachment.

Comment: Your code does not compile. `T_Service.Convert` is not complete, so there might be other issues, but you have a leak because you are never releasing outStream and you should use `RetAttach.SetSourceStream(outStream, soOwned);` instead that will handle releasing that stream when no longer needed.

Comment: Also wrapping `try...finally` in `try..except` with `raise` is pointless. `try...finally` is not used for handling exceptions and it will propagate to the next exception handler. `try..finally` only runs code in finally block regardless of exception

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thats the point. When i release outStream: `finally outStream.Free end;` then i dont have a returned data in a Client, and I have a exception "Access Violation at ...". For TSoapAttachment client shold be release memory.
In Soap.InvokeRegistry.pas theoretically its set: `'RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(TSOAPAttachment, ... ` practically its doesnt work.
`try...try..` for simplicity, I cut out the error handling.

Comment: Yes, you cannot release `outStream` manually, that is why I said you need to use `soOwned `instead of `soReference` so the `outStream` memory will be handled by `RetAttach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are leaking `outStream` because you are passing it as reference to `RetAttach`

```
RetAttach.SetSourceStream(outStream, soReference);
```

You need to use `soOwned` instead as `Ownership` parameter. In that case memory management of `outStream` will be transferred to `RetAttach` instance and it will be automatically handled.

```
RetAttach.SetSourceStream(outStream, soOwned);
```

---

You are also needlessly wrapping `try...finally` with `try...except` that does nothing besides re-raising the exception.

```
  try
    try
      ...
    finally
      FreeAndNil(ReqAttach);
      FreeAndNil(RespAttach);
    end;
  except
    raise;
  end;
```

You should just remove that useless `try...except` block, because following code has exactly the same effect.

```
try
  ...
finally
  FreeAndNil(ReqAttach);
  FreeAndNil(RespAttach);
end;
```

`try...finally` does not handle exception it merely runs code in `finally` block regardless of exception. After that code runs, exception will be automatically propagated to the next exception handler.

---

Additional issue in your code is that `RespAttach` is not initialized to nil and your call `FreeAndNil(RespAttach)` might be running on dangling pointer if the exception happens before it is assigned. Besides that `FreeAndNil` is also redundant here as you are dealing with local variables that are not going to be reused.

```
procedure TClientForm.btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ReqAttach: TSOAPAttachment;
  RespAttach: TSOAPAttachment;
  Service: I_Service;
begin
  RespAttach := nil; 
  ReqAttach := TSOAPAttachment.Create;
  try
    Service := unitIMyService.GetI_Service();
    ReqAttach.SetSourceFile('D:\In.pdf');
    RespAttach := Service.Convert(ReqAttach);
    RespAttach.SaveToFile('D:\Resp.pdf');
  finally
    ReqAttach.Free;
    RespAttach.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `RetAttach.SetSourceStream(outStream, soOwned);` 
This is the solution to the problem.
Thank you very much.